# Loading google maps asynchronously

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to load my google map asynchronously and it works but it is loading the map in twice. If I remove "`box.onload = initialize;`" this stops that problem but then the infobox doesn't show...how do I fix my code so it only loads the map once AND shows the infobox.

```
function loadScript() {
   var map = document.createElement('script');
   map.type = 'text/javascript';
   map.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key_goes_here&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
   document.body.appendChild(map);  

   map.onload = function() {
      var box = document.createElement('script');
      box.type = 'text/javascript';
      box.src = 'https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js';
      document.body.appendChild(box);
      box.onload = initialize;
   };
}           
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: Remove the callback from your map.src

Comment: That stops the map from working altogether :(

Comment: The problem is it looks to me like you're going to end up calling `initialize` twice.  Maybe the box.onload should call a different function

Comment: That's what I thought and that's where I get stuck :(

Comment: Might be useful to add your initialize function to the question too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The map appears twice because you're calling `initialize` twice.

Before fixing that, let's simplify your code a bit. Never let yourself repeat blocks of code like that; instead make it into a common function.

Also, don't load infobox.js from googlecode.com; Google Code is not a CDN. Load your own copy.

So, the code may look like this:

```
function addScript( url, callback ) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    if( callback ) script.onload = callback;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild( script );  
}

function loadMapsAPI() {
    addScript( 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key_goes_here&sensor=false&callback=mapsApiReady' );
}

function mapsApiReady() {
    addScript( 'infobox.js', initialize );
}

window.onload = loadMapsAPI;
```

Comment: Thanks! This has totally fixed my problem :D

Comment: That should be 'addScript( 'infobox.js', initialize );' instead ;)

Comment: @MichaelGeary The best answer ever! None of the other approaches had worked for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

I created this script. You can call this and add any callback function, so you have to just include this to your scripts and call

> **googleMapsLoadAsync(function(){ alert('google maps loaded'); });**

script

```
var googleMapsAsyncLoaded = false;
var googleMapsAsyncCallback = function(){ };

function googleMapsLoadAsync(callback) {

    if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') { googleMapsAsyncCallback=callback; }

    if(!googleMapsAsyncLoaded) {

        $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&async=2&callback=googleMapsAsyncLoadedFunction');

    } else {

        googleMapsAsyncLoadedFunction();

    }

}

function googleMapsAsyncLoadedFunction() {

    googleMapsAsyncLoaded = true;

    if(googleMapsAsyncCallback && typeof(googleMapsAsyncCallback) === "function") {

        googleMapsAsyncCallback();

    }

    googleMapsAsyncCallback = function(){ };

}
```