# Enabling Google maps after data has been switched on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Cordova app with an angular bootstrap kicking in on 'deviceready'.

I have Google maps linked like so:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

If the app starts with data set to off then obviously the script will be missing.

If the user turns on data how can i initialise Google maps? Must i restart the app? I've tried injecting the script via 'document' but the error message said that's not allowed.

Any help or tips would be very much welcomed.

Cheers

Dale

Comment: you can certainly load the Google Maps JS API asynchronously by inserting the script into the DOM.  e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340529/loading-google-maps-asynchronously

Comment: Yes this works as it injects the script into the index.html however, this forces you have a callback function also in the same page - meaning i don't have access to anything in my webapp $scope which is what is required. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this code will check if google maps api libraries are loaded when building a map within your angular controller and try get it if not.

```
//already loaded build the map
if ($window.google && $window.google.maps) {
    prepareMap();
} else {    //not loaded
    //create a promise object
    var mapScriptPromise = getMapScript();
    mapScriptPromise.then(function(){
        prepareMap();   //now you can build the map
    });      
}

//create the hook for the file and return the deferred promise
function getMapScript() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    //script callback
    $window.initMap = function() {
       deferred.resolve();
    }
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initMap";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return deferred.promise;    
}

//add your map settings here i.e.
function prepareMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    ...
}
```