# Why can't I load google maps in angular 2 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular

Here is my ts component:

```
import {Component, OnInit,  Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

    declare var google: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    })


    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'Dashboard';
      private map: any;


        constructor() {
          let brussels = new google.maps.LatLng(50.82, 4.35);
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: brussels
          };
          this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: brussels
          });
          //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ( () => this.select.next("i was a map click")) )
          marker.setMap(this.map);

        }

      ngOnInit(){

      }
```

Here is my html:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<div id="legend-container"><h3>Legend</h3></div>
<div id="info-box" style="">?</div>
```

I declared in the main index.html the api key for google maps. The problem is that I cannot seem to load the google map into the component. There errors in the console are mainly the following:

```
error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: google is not definedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:45(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:209ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:192onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:43ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:191Zone.run @ zone.js:85(anonymous function) @ zone.js:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:225onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:34ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:224Zone.runTask @ zone.js:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:357
error_handler.js:47 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: google is not definedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:209ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:192onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:43ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:191Zone.run @ zone.js:85(anonymous function) @ zone.js:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:225onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:34ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:224Zone.runTask @ zone.js:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:357
error_handler.js:50 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:209ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:192onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:43ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:191Zone.run @ zone.js:85(anonymous function) @ zone.js:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:225onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:34ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:224Zone.runTask @ zone.js:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:357
error_handler.js:51 ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated :)

Comment: google maps is not loaded yet so the `google` namespace is undefined...

Comment: @yurzui I did, but without any luck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the google maps API is not loaded yet you should load it asynchronously an initialize the map after it has been loaded. take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340529/loading-google-maps-asynchronously) about loading google maps asynchronously.

And as @Günter Zöchbauer said you should initialize the map after the view has been initialized. (in `ngAfterViewInit`)

something like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'Dashboard';
  private map: any;

  constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
  }
  onMapsReady(){
    let brussels = new google.maps.LatLng(50.82, 4.35);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: brussels
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: brussels
    });
    //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ( () => this.select.next("i was a map click")) )
    marker.setMap(this.map);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    (<any>window).googleMapsReady=this.onMapsReady.bind(this);
     var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=googleMapsReady";

  }

}
```

**NB**: loading the API via a service would be (much) better

Comment: You've just stopped my 2-day pain.Thank you.. Ok, to understand it. Why is ionic unable to load the remote script from the script tag in the index.html? why do we need to load it that way?

Answer (score 3):

The `googleMap` element doesn't exist in the DOM at this point. Move the code to `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Dashboard';
    private map: any;


    ngAfterViewInit() {
      let brussels = new google.maps.LatLng(50.82, 4.35);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: brussels
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: brussels
      });
      //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ( () => this.select.next("i was a map click")) )
      marker.setMap(this.map);

    }
 }
```

Comment: the error is about `google` not being defined, not the element not existing.

Comment: Then this is the next issue he will run into ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try loading these 2 files from your index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

For more details, refer this - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs