# Error when trying to render Google Map on page

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

#### The Question

I am trying to create a custom implementation of the Google Maps using the API in Angular 2 and TypeScript. I have everything working up to the part where the map should be getting rendered on the page.

Unfortunately, the map renders as a blank gray square, and attempting to interact with it leads to a very nondescript `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` error.

I have read in several other questions on the site that this is usually due to the map attempting to render into a hidden DOM element, load into a DOM element that doesn't exist (not in a page-load function), or that it loses reference to the DOM element it was rendered into.

From what I can see here, I have satisfied all of those conditions, unless I am missing something about the way Angular is working here?

Can somebody please point me in the right direction here?

#### The Code

```
declare let google: any;

/**
 * @Component: Map
 * @Section: Miscellaneous
 * @Description: Generates an interactive map
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'mymap',
    template: `<div #map style="min-width:600px; min-height: 600px;"></div>`
})
export class MyMapComponent {

    // A reference to the map DOM element
    @ViewChild("map") mapEl: ElementRef;

    // A reference to the map object
    map: any;

    // Intializes the map
    initMap: Function = function(){

        // Set the map to a new google map
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapEl.nativeElement, {

            // Default zoom level
            zoom: this.zoomLevel | 6
        })

        console.log(this.map);
    };

    // Sets the center of the map
    setMapCenter: Function = function( latlng: any ){
        if ( this.map && latlng ){
            this.map.setCenter();
        }
    }

    // Callback for the call to the browser to request the users estimated lat/lng
    getUserLocationCallback: any = function( position: any ){

        // Catches a Geoposition object:
        // coords
        //  - accuracy
        //  - altitude
        //  - altitudeAccuracy
        //  - heading
        //  - latitude
        //  - longitude
        //  - speed
        // timestamp
        this.setMapCenter(new google.maps.LatLng({lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.latitude}));
    }

    // On Init
    ngAfterViewInit(){

        // Set the key for the Google Maps API
        var gmap_api_key = "[KEY_REMOVED]";

        // Create the script tag and add it to the document
        var gmap = document.createElement('script');
        gmap.type = 'text/javascript';
        gmap.async = true;
        gmap.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + gmap_api_key;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gmap, s);

        // Wait for the script to load
        var mapsInterval = setInterval( () => {

            // If the script is loaded and the maps functions are available
            if ( typeof google !== "undefined" && google.maps && google.maps.Map){

                // Clear our interval
                clearInterval(mapsInterval);

                // Initialize the map
                this.initMap();

                // Request location from the browser. Arrow function used to maintain scope.
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( () => { this.getUserLocationCallback } );
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * @Property: displayedMarkers
     * @Description: A list of markers current displayed on the map.
     * @Type: array
     * @Two-way: output only
     */
    @Output() displayedMarkersChange: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter;

    /**
     * @Property: mapCenter
     * @Description: lat/long of the center of the map being displayed
     * @Type: object {lat: "N", lng: "N"}
     * @Two-way: true
     */
    @Input()
    set mapCenter( position: any ){

        // If a position was provided
        if ( typeof position !== "undefined" ){

            // Set thet map center using the provided position
            this.setMapCenter( new google.maps.LatLng (position ) );
        }
    }
    @Output() mapCenterChange: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter;

    /**
     * @Property: zoomLevel
     * @Description: Current zoom level of the map. Accepts values between 0 (shows the entire earth) and up 21
     * @Type: array
     * @Two-way: true
     */
    @Input() zoomLevel: number;
    @Output() zoomLevelChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter;

    /**
     * @Property: filters
     * @Description: Filters to be applied to the marker results.
     * @Type: array
     * @Two-way: false
     */
    @Input() filters: any[];
}
```

#### The Plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/pIVOCSJ5eb1PUVXoEffS?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I load google maps in angular 2 component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487377/why-cant-i-load-google-maps-in-angular-2-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thank you for your google maps API key ;-).

Your problem here is that google maps is not loaded yet when trying to interact with it. you need to provide a callback to make it work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487377/why-cant-i-load-google-maps-in-angular-2-component/39487518#39487518) might help.

Comment: Just for other people reading this: The key was to add the callback manually to the window: `(<any>window).googleMapsReady = () => this.initMap();`, add the callback to the URL for the Google maps JS: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=googleMapsReady&key=`, and make sure there was a map center when the map was initialized: `center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.7767, 96.7970)`